# sport !== SPORTS.monthly &&

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am new to react js.
when I add this piece of code its hiding the nav tag
sport !== SPORTS.monthly &&

can you guys tell me why...
its also not inside if condition...
then how come its working like that

```
rendergraph(sport, sportKey, data) {
    let componentToRender = null;
    switch (sport) {
        case SPORTS.yearly:
            componentToRender = (<YearlyDataValues DataValuess={data}/>);
            break;
        case SPORTS.monthly:
            componentToRender = (<MonthlyDataValues DataValuess={data}/>);
            break;
        case SPORTS.quarterly:
            componentToRender = (<QuarterlyDataValues DataValuess={data}/>);
            break;
        case SPORTS.all:
            componentToRender = (<AllDataValues DataValuess={data}/>);
            break;
        default:
            componentToRender = null;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {componentToRender}
            { sport !== SPORTS.monthly &&
                (<nav className="graph-nav">
                    {this.renderPrevious(sport, sportKey)}
                    {
                        // render only if we have data in the store
                        this.dataForRenderer({
                            sport,
                            sportKey: moment(sportKey).add(1, sport.period.toLowerCase()).toDate()
                        }) &&
                        this.renderNext(sport, sportKey)
                    }
                </nav>)
            }
        </div>
    );
},
```

Comment: The condition is clearly falsy, and if the left hand side of `&&` is falsy, there's no need to execute the right hand side.

Comment: @adeneo I am still confused...is there any online example

Comment: When using the logical AND operator, both sides has to be truthy to continue, so it's `THIS && THIS` and if one of them is falsy, it fails. If the one on the left, which is where it starts checking, is falsy, there's no reason the check the statement on the right, it already failed -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6e9h0yz0/

Comment: @adeneo is there any name for this type of statements...first time i am seeing like this